# Changing web.config containing namespace in configuration tag with Inno Setup

Tags: web-config, inno-setup, xml-namespaces

I would like to set a new attribute for a node in a web.config file with installation package created with Inno Setup.
To set this attribute I'm using procedure [SaveAttributeValueToXML](https://gist.github.com/akhansari/fd7ba6a568e88e0709f3).

My web.config -file starts with configuration section with namespace. I'm trying to add one attribute to tag

The web.config -file structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"> 
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <authenticationService enabled="true"/>
        <roleService enabled="true"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

I want to add a new attribute to authenticationService like this:

```
   <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true"/>
```

When I call SaveAttributeValueToXML

```
SaveAttributeValueToXML(ConfigFileName, '/configuration/system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices/authenticationService', 'requireSSL', 'True');
```

the procedure doesn't find the node due to namespace in configuration tag and creates error "Variant is null, cannot invoke" at

```
XMLNode.setAttribute(AAttribute, AValue);
```

When I removed the namespace definition from web.config -file, the above procedure call worked.

For C# there seems to be XmlNamespaceManager which can deal with the xml namespace in the xml document. For Inno Setup, according to [Inno Setup - XML editing XPath request fails with "NIL Interface Exception at runtime"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45716413/850848), I could use

```
XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', xmlns:ns=''http://_namespace_''');.
```

If I change in SaveAttributeValueToXML

```
  XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
  XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:ns=''http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0''');
  XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode('//ns:configuration/system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices/authenticationService');
  XMLNode.setAttribute(AAttribute, AValue);
```

The XMLNode.setAttribute will still create an exception "Variant is null, cannot invoke". So, selectSingleNode is not returning anything. I must have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin Prikryls comments and tips I created this solution to my problem.

I added a new parameter for *Namespace* in procedure SaveAttributeValueToXML.

```
procedure SaveAttributeValueToXML(const AFileName, NameSpace, APath, AAttribute, AValue: string);
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      if Length(NameSpace) > 0 then
        XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:ns=''' + NameSpace + '''');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      XMLNode.setAttribute(AAttribute, AValue);
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, 
      mbError, MB_OK); 
    Log('SaveAttributeValueToXML, AFileName: ' + AFileName + 
      ', APath: ' + APath +
      ', AAttribute: ' + AAttribute +
      ', AValue: ' + AValue); 
  end;
end;
```

In my case I call it like

```
SaveAttributeValueToXML(ConfigFileName, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0', '//ns:configuration/ns:system.web.extensions/ns:scripting/ns:webServices/ns:authenticationService', 'requireSSL', 'True');
```